# How to pass more than one python variables into regex insearch of finding lines from a text file?

Tags: python, regex

How  to  find  line-set  from a log file starting  with 5 and has to have 2  timestamp values of start-time and end-time with  a   format    (eg:14/05/02 02:30:00)  which could be  entered by user using ***RegularExpression*** ?

I need a script to search through each and every line from my log file in-search of 3 arguments:

**1)** start time(input by user) eg: *14/05/02 02:30:00* 
  **2)** end time(input by user)   eg: *14/05/02 02:45:00*
  **3)** line start with number "5"

sample lines of my log file:

```
9,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94767539135,94767539135,0,1,172839,0,1,172839,,14/05/02 02:30:00,9477000003,,,,,93,14/05/02 03:30:00,0,0,9477000008,,false,,,,,,,,false,0,5011405020230005756,67000,
5,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94776082043,94776082043,0,1,77100,0,1,77100,,14/05/02 02:30:00,9477000003,,,,,19,14/05/05 02:30:00,0,0,9477000007,9477000003,false,,,,,,,,true,,,0,,5011405020230005752,
11,14/05/02 02:30:00,94776082043,1,9477000051,,,5011405020230005752,
12,14/05/02 02:30:00,true,false,9477000008,413025705057121,,,,5011405020230005748,
3,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94713784377,0,1,1,94771653521,0,1,0713784377,,14/05/02 02:29:48,9477000003,413021500734521,,,,0,14/05/05 02:29:50,,,9477000006,9477000006,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,5011405020229484460,
9,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94771969046,94771969046,0,1,776236,0,1,776236,,14/05/02 02:30:00,9477000003,,,,,62,14/05/05 02:30:00,0,0,9477000008,,false,,,,,,,,false,0,5011405020230005763,67000,
5,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94771059909,94771059909,1,1,94776716217,1,1,94776716217,,14/05/02 02:29:57,9477000003,413020776716217,,,,54,14/05/05 02:29:55,0,0,9477000006,9477000047,false,,,,,,,,false,,,0,,5011405020229575408,
```

This is the part of code i tried :

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

    import re

    count=0

    fh = open(r"/home/harzyne/pythonscripts/read_log_file.txt")

    yyyy,mo,dd,hh,mm = raw_input("Enter Start_Time in format(yy,mm,dd,hh,mm)").split(',')
    yyyy1,mo1,dd1,hh1,mm1 =raw_input("Enter End_Time in format(yy,mm,dd,hh,mm)").split(',')

    for i in fh:
         if re.search('^5',i):
                count +=1
    print count

try:
    #start_t = datetime(2014,5,2,02,30)
    #end_t = datetime(2014,5,2,02,45)
    start_t = datetime(int(yyyy),int(mo),int(dd),int(hh),int(mm))
    end_t = datetime(int(yyyy1),int(mo1),int(dd1),int(hh1),int(mm1))
    diff = end_t - start_t

except ValueError:
    print ("invalid arguement")
    #start = raw_input("Enter Start_Time in format(yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mm) ")
    #end = raw_input("Enter End_Time in format(yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mm)")


no_of_msg_per_sec = float(count)/diff.seconds
print no_of_msg_per_sec
```

Comment: Must the End_Time lines be included in the final result?

Comment: result(output) should be number of lines which starts with 5 and has timestamp with start_time value or end_time value.
I need a script to search through each and every line from my log file in-search of 3 arguments: **1) start time(input by user) eg: 14/05/02 02:30:00 2) end time(input by user) eg: 14/05/02 02:45:00 3) line start with number "5"**

Comment: If I understand well, you don't want to count possible lines between these two timestamps?

Comment: i have to give output for "how many messages sent per second between the time gap" so i need to get no.of.lines where messages sent during the time gap.

Comment: Given start = `02:30:00` and end = `02:45:00`, do you also want lines that lie inside this gap, for example `02:35:00-02:40:00`?

Comment: no.just the two given are enough to search .. Thats simply i need a regex to find ((start with 5) AND ((start_time) OR (end_time)))

Comment: can u able to find out ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to build the search pattern and to count the lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

s = '''9,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94767539135,94767539135,0,1,172839,0,1,172839...
5,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94776082043,94776082043,0,1,77100,0,1,77100,,14/05/0...
11,14/05/02 02:30:00,94776082043,1,9477000051,,,5011405020230005752,
12,14/05/02 02:30:00,true,false,9477000008,413025705057121,,,,50114050202300...
3,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94713784377,0,1,1,94771653521,0,1,0713784377,,14/05/...
9,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94771969046,94771969046,0,1,776236,0,1,776236,,14/05...
5,14/05/02 02:29:59,1,1,94771059909,94771059909,1,1,94776716217,1,1,94776...'''

start_sb = r'14/05/02 02:29:59'
end_sb = r'14/05/02 02:30:00'

p = re.compile(r'^5,' + end_sb + r',.*\n([\s\S]*?)^5,' + start_sb + r',', re.M)

m = p.search(s)

if (m):
    print m.group(1).count("\n")
else
    print 'no result'
```

The idea is to put all the content between the start and end limits in a capture group and then to count the number of newline characters in this group.

**About the pattern itself:**

`.*` will match all characters until the end of the line
`[\s\S]` is a famous trick to match all characters including newlines
`([\s\S]*?)` is the capture group 1, it uses a lazy quantifier to grab all until the first line that begins with 5 and the start datetime.

The `re.M` option *(`MULTILINE`)* changes the meaning of the `^` anchor from *start of string* to *start of line*.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = '''9,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94767539135,94767539135,0,1,172839,0,1,172839...
5,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94776082043,94776082043,0,1,77100,0,1,77100,,14/05/0...
11,14/05/02 02:30:00,94776082043,1,9477000051,,,5011405020230005752,
12,14/05/02 02:30:00,true,false,9477000008,413025705057121,,,,50114050202300...
3,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94713784377,0,1,1,94771653521,0,1,0713784377,,14/05/...
9,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94771969046,94771969046,0,1,776236,0,1,776236,,14/05...
5,14/05/02 02:29:59,1,1,94771059909,94771059909,1,1,94776716217,1,1,94776...'''

start = r'14/05/02 02:29:59'
end = r'14/05/02 02:30:00'

regex = r'(^5.*(?:' + start + '|' + end + ').*$)'

matches = re.findall(regex, text, re.M)

print matches
```

This will match any line that:

- begins with a 5
- contains either start OR end

So your `count` would be `len(matches)`.

Output:

```
['5,14/05/02 02:30:00,1,1,94776082043,94776082043,0,1,77100,0,1,77100,,14/05/0...',
'5,14/05/02 02:29:59,1,1,94771059909,94771059909,1,1,94776716217,1,1,94776...']
```